# why Visual Studio 2019 reporting not show up when add new item?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I installed Microsoft visual studio 2019 professional and installed SAP crystal reports

SP25 for visual studio 2019 from this link :

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2019/

but when I opened my project I cannot open my reports also when I try to add new item I cannot find reporting option to add new crystal report ,
What is the missing and how to add reporting to visual studio 2019 ?

please see the image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After searching the problem I removed the installed crystal reports and installed the last version SP 30 and complete version with 64 bit runtime from SAP website

```
https://www.sap.com/cmp/td/sap-crystal-reports-visual-studio-trial.html
```

Then reporting show up in VS 2019 and I can make and run crystal reports .